# Why am I getting 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

In my index.ios.js, I have the following:

```
  renderScene(route, navigator){
    return <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
  }
```

and

```
render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{name: 'FirstPage', component: FirstPage}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
```

then in my FirstPage.js, to navigate to the SecondPage.js:

```
  _navigate(){
    this.props.navigator.replace({
      component: SecondPage,
      name: 'SecondPage'
    })
  }
```

Then in my SecondPage.js, it just renders the component  in a . And in my ThirdPage.js:

```
  _rowPressed(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: FourthPage,
      name: 'FourthPage',
    })
  }


  <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => this._rowPressed()}
  >
     <View>
          <Text>Go to FourthPage</Text>
     </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

Then in my FourthPage.js, I simply have:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    This is FourthPage.js
  </View>
```

I am getting the error from the ThirdPage.js, which says:

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in _rowPressed()
```

and I cannot seem to figure out why, because the this.props.navigator.push worked fine for both .replace and .push, but now I am getting this error. Any guidance or insight would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: push is a function on arrays and this.props.navigator is an object.

Comment: @JohnS Navigator indeed has `push` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Comment: OP did you bind your `_rowPressed` method to the component in your constructor?

Comment: @JohnS As far as I know, this.props.navigator.push works on objects.

Comment: @azium Sorry but could you clarify on what you mean? This is what I have as my constructor: constructor(props){ super(props);}

Comment: @JoKo TIL. Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

```
<TouchableHighlight
    onPress={this._rowPressed.bind(this)}//add this
  >
     <View>
          <Text>Go to FourthPage</Text>
     </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

you may just need to bind the Component

Comment: I tried it and no error but the method '_rowPressed*()' is somehow not being called, and I can't seem to figure out why... tried console.log inside _rowPressed() and it is not logging even though it is being called via onPress. What could be the issue?

Comment: try this this._rowPressed.bind(this)

Comment: Actually it works and calls the method and logs correctly, but now I am getting the following error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: navigator.props.push()  try this